# Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu/ubuntu-make'

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I tried adding PPA but got this error:

> Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu/ubuntu-make'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`

If still does not work, then run: `sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:ppaname/ppa`