# Why cannot add PPA deadsnakes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, apt

I have ubuntu version 20.04 and I would like to install python 3.6 from the shell. After `sudo apt install software-properties-common` I am trying to use the `add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` command but I am getting this error:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~deadsnakes/ubuntu/ppa'.
ERROR: '~deadsnakes' user or team does not exist
```

Did I forget any steps or does the repository no longer work?

Comment: hmm, are you sure you need that `~` character in front of the team name? Maybe I'm missing some syntax detail there, but `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` is what's recommended [here](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Comment: @kuropan I'm running into the same issue, and I'm not adding the `~`, it's added by the add-apt-repository command.

Answer (score 25):

You're probably behind a corporate proxy and to add `-E` to your sudo command to preserve the environment variables.

```bash
$ sudo add-apt-repository -y 'ppa:deadsnakes/ppa'
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~deadsnakes/ubuntu/ppa'.
ERROR: '~deadsnakes' user or team does not exist.
$ sudo -E add-apt-repository -y 'ppa:deadsnakes/ppa'
 This PPA contains more recent Python versions packaged for Ubuntu.

Disclaimer: there's no guarantee of timely updates in case of security problems or other issues. If you want to use them in a security-or-otherwise-critical environment (say, on a production server), you do so at your own risk.

Update Note
===========
...
```

Comment: If you're on WSL, and this doesn't fix it: Make sure you're not behind a proxy; make sure WSL can connect to anything at all (`ping 8.8.8.8`), if not, restart WSL (in powershell: `wsl --shutdown`).

Comment: I don't have sudo what should i do then?

Comment: @MoeinHasani are your proxy variables set?

Answer (score 14):

I got this error with a fresh Ubuntu installation in a VM and none of the other answers worked for me. However, this command solved the problem for me:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

*(Credits: this was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48674704/10669875) at a related question.)*

Comment: life saving comment

Answer (score 13):

For people having issues running this within a Dockerfile, changing:

```
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

to:

```
RUN add-apt-repository 'ppa:deadsnakes/ppa'
```

Fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This combined with RUN apt-get install -y tzdata software-properties-common

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but was on a Docker container, so no `sudo` was avilable. I was able to manually add the repository at `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main
```

I was on 16.04, so used `xenial`.

then:

```sh
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com/ --recv-keys BA6932366A755776
```

You should be able to install python 3.6 with

```sh
apt-get install python3.6
```

Answer (score 3):

Just type this before running ppa command:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common -y
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the existence of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`? After messing around with my ppa, I found that I had not created that directory.
If this is also your case, please do

```
$ sudo mkdir /etc/apt/sources.list.d
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

also, as @kuropan suggested, there is no need for add the ~ before 'deadsnakes'

I'm using ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Do you copy this command from a certain web page?
Maybe there are some invisible character in it.
Try to enter it manually.