# Cannot add PPA deadsnakes to Ubuntu 18.04 behind company proxy

Tags: ubuntu, repository, python-3.11

When I try to add ppa repository to Ubuntu with
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`
I get

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~deadsnakes/ubuntu/ppa'.
ERROR: '~deadsnakes' user or team does not exist
```

the same command works outside the company network so I suppose it is a matter of proxy settings.
For apt I set up a config file with

```
Acquire {
  HTTP::proxy "http://123.456.789.10:81/";
  HTTPS::proxy "http://123.456.789.10:81/";
}
```

and with that all the sudo apt install work also within the company network.

Following [Why cannot add PPA deadsnakes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66597894/why-cannot-add-ppa-deadsnakes/67619514#67619514)
I tried:
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`
set up an environment variable with
`export HTTPS_PROXY=http://@123.456.789.10:81`
then run
`sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:ppaname/ppa`
but I get the same error